# New line in Button text \n

Tags: javascript, button, sapui5

I use JavaScript to design a SAPUI5 application.
For my Button I want a text which is split in to lines.
But `\n` doesn't work. So how can I display a text in a button which expands over two lines?

Answer (score 1):

The Button text is escaped before it is written to the DOM, therefore you cannot add HTML tags to the text (see [source](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/ButtonRenderer.js#L196)).

To make a two-lined Button, I would suggest to [extend](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f184586f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) the Button control and provide your custom renderer which takes care of adding the new line.

Comment: How exactly can I do that? never did something like this before :/ And where do I have to place that new definition?

Comment: Have a look at the linked page from the Developer Guide. Generally you could copy a lot from the `sap.m.Button` and only change the one linked line. Just have a try and feel free to ask another questions if you get stuck.